# How to solve equations in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, trigonometry, solver

I am creating a program that calculates the temperature distribution of a slab based on some boundary conditions using Visual Basic. During the development, I need to solve equations like this one:

```
tan(x*L) = x * (H1 + H2) / (x^2 - H1*H2)
```

The variable in this case is x, and the constants L, H1 and H2 are given. I don't believe Visual Basic has a native solver so I need help in this one.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro Guaraldi

Comment: Are you attempting to solve for `x`, or are you just trying to use VB.NET to solve the equation and `x` will be known when the formula is run?

Comment: You are correct that the .NET FCL does not have a built-in equation solver.  You'll need to either find a third-party library that meets your needs or write your own.

Comment: Are you restricted to VB .NET or just .NET ? If so you could give F#.

Comment: @Tim I am trying to solve for x, the value is not known, another important detail is that there are infinite multiple roots for that equation, so what I need is to find those roots.

Comment: @AlexB. I am actually new to this programming language, so I am using the Visual Basic provided by Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: As this is a physical system, it seems unlikely that *x* will have more than one value at any location. Further, if you have a reasonable approximation to *x* at some point (L, H1, H2) then you can use the [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to refine *x*. Values of *x'* for nearby values of L', H1' and H2' will be close to *x*. Usually.

Comment: ... and for a more accurate approximation, you could use [Finite element analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [nonlinear solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solver) and I'm sure there are solvers that have an interface you can use from VB. Alternatively you can write a file and call a solver as a subprocess.

Here's an example in [AMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL) that illustrates the idea:

```
# test.ampl
param H1 = 3;
param H2 = 4;
param L = 5;
var x >= 0.1; # set lower bound to 0.1, because 0 is a trivial solution
s.t. c: tan(x*L) = x * (H1 + H2) / (x^2 - H1*H2);
option solver knitro;
solve;
print x;
```

this produces the following output:

```
KNITRO 9.1.0: Locally optimal solution.
objective 0; feasibility error 6.08e-11
6 iterations; 7 function evaluations
Objective = find a feasible point.
1.701346690729009
```

Comment: Interesting... how long did it take to calculate that solution? Also, what happened to x = 0.563225 and x = 1.12957? (See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+tan%28x*5%29+%3D+x+*+%283+%2B+4%29+%2F+%28x%5E2+-+3*4%29) Edit: looks like you'll have to copy and paste that link...

Comment: @charliefox2 Took about 1 millisecond (I guess mostly the time to start the process =)). This finds one solution, for multiple solution you can either provide different starting points or take into account periodicity or whatever.

Comment: Any reason it skipped over the first two non-trivial positive solutions and went straight to 1.70135? Side note - I'm gonna have to look into how this thing works, and see if I can integrate it into VB or C# for my own projects, because that is pretty cool.

Comment: No idea. You can force it to find other solutions by setting bounds accordingly, e.g. x <= 1.7. Together with starting point of 0.1 this actually finds 0.5632249084264669 solution.

Comment: That's odd - if you loop it to solve multiple times does it spit out the same solution each time?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm. You can have random multistart. I think the default is deterministic giving the same solutions on the same inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## To my knowledge, this is not an equation you can solve by hand, or elegantly within a program.

**If you need to solve this within a program and brute force is not an option, it seems you are simply out of luck. If you can solve it using external resources, scroll down for the solution.**

*I'd like to preface by apologizing for the equation formatting. Unfortunately StackOverflow does not support MathJax at this time.*

I went ahead and graphed your equation with some arbitrary constants to see what we were looking at here. What you have is:

`f(x) = tan(L*x)`

`g(x) = x * (H1 + H2) / (x^2 - H1 * H2)`

I chose arbitrary constants of `H1 = 3`, `H2 = 4`, and `L = 5`, giving me the equations

`f(x) = tan(5x)`

`g(x) = 7x / (x^2 - 12)`

What you are trying to find is the point where these functions intersect - `f(x) = g(x)`. However, it's easier to look at it if everything is on one side. We'll denote this new equation `h(x)`

`h(x) = tan(5x) - [7x / (x^2 - 12)]`

Now we have one graph, and what you are solving for is `h(x) = 0`, or everywhere our graph crosses the x-axis (our real roots). Here's what that looks like (ignore the vertical bars, they are asymptotes):

[image: h(x) = tan(5x) - (7x / (x^2 - 12))]

As you can see, we're looking at a LOT of solutions - this graph is just from -0.6 to 0.6! With that, if we ask WolframAlpha to [solve for h(x) = 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20tan%285x%29%20-%20%287x%20%2F%20%28x%5E2%20-%2012%29%29%20%3D%200), we get a lot of numbers. That's just with the standard computation time - there are plenty more to calculate.

### So if WolframAlpha can solve it, then what's the problem?

The problem is that your application is not, nor is it likely to become, as powerful as the WolframAlpha servers. While you *could* write a function to brute force calculate it by testing value after value for x, I don't know how fast you expect the equation to be solved.

### So what's the problem with my equation, then?

The problem with your equation is `tan(L*x)`. To start, if you have a trig function in your equation, there's just almost no way to get it out (barring select special cases). Since your variable is inside your trig function and trig functions are cyclical (that is, they repeat), you essentially get an infinite number of answers.

### But I NEED to solve this equation programmatically!

Reading your question, I was unclear as to whether you had to solve it within VB.NET, or if you could calculate the value using graphing, or a source like WolframAlpha.

At first, when you look at the values for x where h(x) = 0, you might think they increase linearly - unfortunately, they do not. This means you would need to solve for each value individually - and depending on how many solutions you are looking for, that's a lot of calculations.

### What if I don't need to do it within a program, and can use a source like WolframAlpha?

Then your equation is `tan(L*x) - [x * (H1 + H2) / (x^2 - H1 * H2)] = 0`. Plug in your constants, and then ask [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)!

Comment: WolframAlpha just uses a nonlinear solver. There is no special about it and no reason why it couldn't be solved from a user app with one of the many solvers available.